# Event not fire if site is open with IP

Tags: sharepoint

Item Adding,Item updating event not fire is my site is open with IP address. If site open with server name then all event work fine.Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Check the alternate access mapping for the site in Central Administration. You may have to bind IP at IIS and create an alternate access mapping in Central Administration.

http://techblurt.com/2011/03/24/sharepoint-alternate-access-by-ip-address/